Trying to implement dynamic icons in weather app getting: String interpolation can only appear inside a string literal
Building a basic weather app with some hidden functionalities. I am trying to implement dynamic weather icons but I'm getting the above error. I'm new to Swift and to be honest it's been a minute since I have done any coding.
I am getting the error on this line Image(systemName: \(icon))
struct WeatherView: View {
    
    var weather: ResponseBody
    
    var icon = ""

     mutating func dIcon(){
        if weather.weather[0].main == "Clouds" {
                icon = "clouds"
                } else {
                icon = "sun.max"
                }
        }

    var body: some View {
            
        ZStack(alignment: .leading){
            VStack{
                VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 5){
                    Text(weather.name)
                        .bold().font(.title)
                    
                    Text("Today, \(Date().formatted(.dateTime.month().day().hour().minute()))")
                        .fontWeight(.light)
                }
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
                
                Spacer()
                
                VStack{
                    HStack{
                        VStack(spacing: 20){
                            Image(systemName: icon)
                            //Image(systemName: "cloud")
                                .font(.system(size: 40))



You just need Image(systemName: icon).

@Rudedog thats what I tried first but then it started giving me a different error about "Cannot assign property: 'self' is immutable. " and type'()" cannot conform to 'View'".  I understand this is because var in structs are automatically assigned this way. I moved the if statement under a Mutating func that reassigns the variable but struggling to figure out how to call it. I have updated the code snip it to reflect the change i have made.

You can’t have mutating funcs in a SwiftUI struct. It’s not even clear why you want that. If I was designing this view, I would remove dIcon() and make icon a computed property, something like
var icon: String {
  if weather.weather[0].main == "Clouds" {
    “clouds”
  } else {
    “sun.max”
  }
}

